# Python Prefect 2.9.0 - TypeError: 'fn' must be callable

Tags: python-3.x, scheduling, prefect

I'm currently learning Python Prefect and I'm using version 2.9.0. I'm trying to set up scheduling with a 10-second interval using the following code:

```
@task
def print_values():
    print("Test 1: "+ datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

with Flow("my-flow") as flow:
    print_values()

flow.run_config(
    {"scheduler": IntervalSchedule(interval=timedelta(seconds=10))}
)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\...\testworkflow\testSchedule.py", line 17, in <module>
    with Flow("my-flow") as flow:
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\prefect\context.py", line 178, in __register_init__
    __init__(__self__, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\.conda\envs\testenv\lib\site-packages\prefect\flows.py", line 144, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'fn' must be callable")
TypeError: 'fn' must be callable
```

I've searched on Stack Overflow and looked in the documentation, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `Flow` takes a function as an argument, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

For Prefect 2 you want to use the @flow decorator.

I would update to the latest Prefect version.

If you want a task and a flow you could do something like this:

```py
from prefect import task, flow
from datetime import datetime

@task(log_prints=True)
def print_values():
    print("Test 1: "+ datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

@flow()
def demo():
    print_values()
```

When connected to Prefect Cloud or a Prefect server instance, here's code you could run in the CLI that would create the deployment and schedule and send it to the connected server.

```bash
prefect deployment build my_file_path.py:demo -n my_deploy -p my_process_pool --interval 10 -a
```

You would just need a work pool named `my_process` and to start a worker to poll for work from that work pool. Then you should see runs every 10 seconds.

There are a few ways to create deployments and schedules. Here are the [deployment docs](https://docs.prefect.io/latest/concepts/deployments/) and [scheduling docs](https://docs.prefect.io/latest/concepts/schedules/).